# UFT/QTP Unable to click on toggle button

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, uft-api

I'm unable to click on Toggle button, my scenario is if Toggle/switch button is on then I want to turn it off, if my toggle button is off then I need to turn on one by one.. and toggle/switch button is dynamic..

I tried to automate using index.. but Index.. is getting changed dynamically.

[image]

Comment: UFT also supports the XPath property (like Selenium). Theoretically a combination of the parent elements should be unique, and then what you need is teh first checkbox under the parent

Comment: @BelaTamasJozsa I tried with parent xpath, but unable to click on the toggle button one by one...   Tried below option using dp..

Comment: @BelaTamasJozsa I tried with parent xpath, but unable to click on the toggle button one by one...

set objckbx = description.create
objckbx ("xpath").value = xpath
objckbx ("class").value= "fdl-Toggle-fdl-Toggle-round ng untouched ng pristine ng-valid".